# What is the different between express and express-generator

Tags: node.js, express

As you might know, `express` released 4.1.0 recently. Now you can not use the command line "express" directly via `npm intall -g express` which is working just well in version 3.x. When I read the `Readme` in the package, I saw `express-generator`. After `npm install -g express-generator`, I can use the command line. So,what's the difference? Only for global install?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With express 4 the express boilerplate generator command line was extracted to it's own module 'express-generator' because the generator app did not really share code with express web framework and express and generator app can be released independently.

I guess this was a step into the right direction to decouple the web framework from the boilerplate/skeleton generator since this makes express even more lightweight and leverages tools like yeoman that focus on generating things.

Comment: Does that mean 'express-generator' has the same 'core' with 'express' framework,I mean 'express-generator' can do the same thing which 'express' can do?Now I use 'express-generator' instead of 'express' and I have not yet found any difference.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that with Express 4, a lot of middleware and other things that were not necessary for "core" Express were exported into separate modules. The Express project generator happened to be one of those things.