# node express-generator not getting installed on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, express, npm

I am trying to install express-generator on my ubuntu 14.04 by running this command

`sudo npm install express-generator -g`

it shows that `express-generator` is installed

```
sinscary@avenger:~$ sudo npm install express-generator -g
[sudo] password for sinscary: 
/home/sinscary/.node/bin/express -> /home/sinscary/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.4 /home/sinscary/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@2.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

but i don't know why when i run `express -h` i am continuously getting this error

```
The program 'express' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install node-express
```

I am able to install express with `sudo apt-get install node-express`
 this command but i read somewhere that the prefered way of installing `express-generator` is with `npm`.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445007/npm-install-express-generator-not-installing-express) is similar to my problem but solution given here didn't work for me. As i can see by comparing the answer given here, in my case `npm` is placing the binary links in `/home/username/.node/bin` instead of `/home/username/npm/bin`

So i added `export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH` to my `.bashrc` file but still getting the same error.

I have followed step by step to install express as suggested in [Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) , but still facing the same problem.

Any help on that

Comment: Does it run if you invoke it with the full path: `~/.node/bin/express` ?

Comment: yes it does, but when i run only `express` i am facing same problem.

Comment: The .bashrc change should have really fixed it for you then. Odd. If you haven't already checked, I'd make sure that the .bashrc file is really running (do an `echo $PATH` to make sure the `PATH` change has taken effect). Maybe `PATH` gets overwritten again later in that or some other dotfile?

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, i don't know why but when i restarted my laptop and ran `express` it worked, I don't know why but restarting the laptop does the job.

Comment: You made a change to your `.bashrc`, but that doesn't change your current operating environment. You have to tell `bash` to "reload" the file. you can do that with `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc` (`.` and `source` are aliases to each other) or you can start a new terminal session, which will load the new file OR you can restart your computer, which will, of course, load the new version of that file. Good luck.